# Small php modification - quantity subtotal product page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I found snippet which displays quantity subtotal on product page:

```html
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'variable_product_total_amount_qty_change', 10, 3 );
function variable_product_total_amount_qty_change( $data, $product, $variation ) {

    $data['price_html'] .= '<div id="product_total_price" class="total-price-qty variable_products">Product Total: <span class="price">'.$data['display_price'].'</span></div>';
?>
    <script>
   jQuery(function($){
       jQuery( '.variations_form' ).each( function() {
    jQuery(this).on( 'found_variation', function( event, variation ) {
        console.log(variation);//all details here
var price = variation.display_price;//selectedprice
        console.log(price);
var currency = '<?php echo   get_woocommerce_currency_symbol(); ?>';            
        $('[name=quantity]').change(function(){
        if ((this.value > 1)) { 
 var product_total = parseFloat(price * this.value);
$('#product_total_price').fadeIn();
 $('#product_total_price .price').html( currency + product_total.toFixed(2));
                } else {
 $('#product_total_price').fadeOut();
                }
        });
                });
            });
        });  

    </script>
<?php

return $data;
}
```

In result it displays:
Product Total: zł 100

How to modify code te get:
Product Total: 100 zł BRUTTO

?

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. It'd be very helpful if you could expand your question with a code sample of your best effort to solve the problem so far.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this line has your result HTML:

`$('#product_total_price .price').html( currency + product_total.toFixed(2));`

You just need to change variables order and concatenate the string you want.

`$('#product_total_price .price').html( product_total.toFixed(2) + ' ' + currency + 'BRUTTO');`

Please test it.

Edit: this line is an jQuery command to change the inner HTML of the tag with class 'price' and having parent with id 'product_total_price'. I don't know if there is an side effect (for example if the program get the value from there for someting else). Probably not, because it already has currency and product_total variables, but you should test anyway.

Comment: 1 more question:
Now it appears: 
Product Total: 100

I have to change quantity to display full line:
Product Total: 100 zł brutto

Is it possible to set always full text (zł brutto)?